# How would I turn these raw_input answers and input them into my functions?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to coding so bear with me but how do I make this code work? I'm trying to take the information that is entered by the user and input it into my functions so I can print the total.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

def plane_cost(city):
    if city == "Atlanta":
        return 220
    elif city == "Boston":
        return 550
    elif city == "Chicago":
        return 900

def rental_car_cost(days):
    if days >= 7:
        return days * 100 - 50
    elif days >= 1 and days <= 5:
        return days * 100 - 20

a = raw_input("Please choose number of nights: ")
b = raw_input("Please choose which city you are flying to (Atlanta, Boston, Chicago) ")
c = raw_input("Please choose days of rental car use: ")
d = raw_input("Please choose how much spending money you plan on spending: ")

a = nights
b = city
c = days


total = a + b + c + d

print "Your total cost of trip is %d" % total
```

Comment: use `int("123")` to convert text "123" into integer `123`

Comment: don't assign `night` to `a` because you override value from `raw_input`

Comment: to use function you have to call it `hotel_cost(a)`, or `result = hotel_cost(a)`

Comment: Plus what happens if you want to rent a  car for 6 days??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first convert your numeric input values to numbers and then pass your input values to your functions.

Delete the lines

```
a = nights
b = city
c = days
```

Calculate your total with

```
total = hotel_cost(int(a)) + plane_cost(b) + rental_car_cost(int(c)) + float(d)
```

I assumed that for the number of nights and rental car days only integers make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies in Python version 2. However, you could try this:

```
a = int(raw_input("Please choose number of nights: ") * 140 ) 
# Multiplies by 140, but this would defeat the purpose of your functions.
```

And apply the int function to convert all of your inputs into integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input()` in Python 2 as it evaluates the input to the correct type. For the functions, you just need to pass your values into them, like this:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

def plane_cost(city):
    if city == "Atlanta":
        return 220
    elif city == "Boston":
        return 550
    elif city == "Chicago":
        return 900

def rental_car_cost(days):
    if days >= 7:
        return days * 100 - 50
    elif days >= 1 and days <= 5:
        return days * 100 - 20

nights = input("Please choose number of nights: ")
city = raw_input("Please choose which city you are flying to (Atlanta, Boston, Chicago) ")
rental_duration = input("Please choose days of rental car use: ")
spending_money = input("Please choose how much spending money you plan on spending: ")

total = hotel_cost(nights) + plane_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(rental_duration) + spending_money

print "Your total cost of trip is %d" % total
```

Comment: don't trust user input

Comment: True, but the OP didn't ask me not to